# Python Class Inheritance -Mean, error:mean is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, user-defined-functions

I need to do a class inheritance of the mean function. My code is supposed to calculate the mean of a specific row of data. The desired row is input by the end user. When I try to run my code, I get this error message :

```
class newMean(mean):
NameError: name 'mean' is not defined
```

What am I missing in my code that would recognize that mean is from statistics?

This is my code:

```py
class newMean(mean):

    'a subclass of mean that implements method readAndComputeMean_SM '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it from statistics package.
like:

```
from statistics import mean
```